# Multiple type support (float, int and string) in argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am using json with python to communicate with a server, and I would like to define the type of the data with argparse. Is there way to support Int and Float and String? I know that by default the argparse arguments are strings.

In the below snippet, I want to send a jsonArray that can send different datatypes (currently its only int).

```py
parser.add_argument("-v", "--value", nargs="+", default=[0], type=int, help="Values that will be written (Only Write and WriteComplete)")
```

I have a data type argument. This is needed for the device that is used to communicate after the server processes my request.

```py
parser.add_argument("-dt", "--data-type", help="Data type of the sub indices (i.e. \"uint32\")")
```

So I was thinking to use this parameter to define if it is a float, int or a string.

Comment: How would you decide whether a value is an int or a float or a string? What about a number that's supposed to be a string?

Comment: Are you trying to interpret *literals* perhaps? As in ``"1.2"`` is a ``str``, ``4.5`` is a ``float`` and ``42`` is an ``int``?

Comment: I have a data type argument. This is needed for the device that is used to communicate after the server processes my request. 

parser.add_argument("-dt", "--data-type", help="Data type of the sub indices (i.e. \"uint32\")")

So I was thinking to use this parameter to define if it is a float, int or a string.

Comment: Seems as if the *argument* itself still is a ``str`` then, and your own code has to do the interpretation.

Comment: How to connect two arguments with each other? For example I would like to process the **data_type** string and send the result to the **type** from value argument

Comment: ``argparse`` cannot connect two arguments. You have to write your own code that interprets the ``value`` based on the ``data_type``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I posted an answer to my question. Since you said it can't be done I used a function for detect the value.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out you cannot connect two arguments together. My solution to this is to create a function that compares the two arguments that I want to interact.

```py
def convertValue(value, dataType):
    intTypes = ["int8", "int16", "int32", "int64", "uint8", "uint16", "uint32", "uint64"]
    if dataType in intTypes:
        return int(value, 0)

    floatTypes = ["float", "double"]
    if dataType in floatTypes:
        return float(value)

    return value
```

When generating the JSON request I call the above function.

```py
"data": {
    "values": [convertValue(v, dataType) for v in value],
    "type": dataType,
}
```

Comment: You can write your ``convertValue`` also using a ``dict``: given ``converters = {"int8": int, "int16": int, ..., "float": float, "double": float}``, you can use it as ``coverters.get(data_type, lambda x: x)(value)``. This has the added benefit of being an O(1) lookup versus an O(n) lookup.